# Unable to fetch sql db data from Google cloud sql in Google app service using flask sqlalchemy python app

Tags: python, flask, google-app-engine, flask-sqlalchemy, google-cloud-sql

I have a web app which connects to google cloud sql and fetches data. This app works properly on localhost, that is, it can fetch data from the cloud sql database properly. But when I deploy the app on Google App Engine, the home page loads but when I click on function to fetch data from the database, it doesn't work.

Here is the Logs in the logs explorer (only relevant parts):

```
{
  "textPayload": "[error] 33#33: *496 upstream prematurely closed connection while reading response header from upstream,  server: , request: \"POST /display_all HTTP/1.1\", 
  "logName": "/logs/appengine.googleapis.com%2Fnginx.error",
}
```

Here is the code:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, url_for
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
import csv
import os
import urllib
import datetime
import time

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = 'False'

PASSWORD ="mypwd"
PUBLIC_IP_ADDRESS ="myip"
DBNAME ="mydb"
PROJECT_ID ="myprojectid"
INSTANCE_NAME ="myinstance"


# configuration
app.config["SECRET_KEY"] = "mysecretkey"
app.config["SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI"]= f"mysql+mysqldb://root:{PASSWORD}@{PUBLIC_IP_ADDRESS}:3306/{DBNAME}?unix_socket=/cloudsql/connectionname"

db = SQLAlchemy(app)

class table(db.Model):
    _id = db.Column('_id', db.Integer, primary_key = True)
    time = db.Column(db.String(50))

    def __init__(self, time):
        self.time = time

@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    return render_template('index.html')


@app.route('/display_all', methods = ['GET', 'POST'])
def search_all():
    ans = db.session.execute("select * from table LIMIT 10;")
    return render_template('display_table.html', ans = ans)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    db.create_all()
    app.run()
```

When I look up the error this is what I found (https://github.com/owncloud/client/issues/5706), is this what's wrong? How should I turn off buffering if that's the case?

Am I missing something with the app.yaml file or requirements.txt file?
Here they are:

app.yaml file:

In the line with cloud_sql_instances what would be "MY-DATABASE" here? Would it be the database name or the instance name?

```
runtime: python
env: flex
entrypoint: gunicorn -b :$PORT app:app

runtime_config:
  python_version: 3

# This sample incurs costs to run on the App Engine flexible environment.
# The settings below are to reduce costs during testing and are not appropriate
# for production use. For more information, see:
# https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/configuring-your-app-with-app-yaml

# # Enable a Unix domain socket
beta_settings:
  cloud_sql_instances: <MY-PROJECT>:<INSTANCE-REGION>:<MY-DATABASE>

manual_scaling:
  instances: 1
resources:
  cpu: 1
  memory_gb: 0.5
  disk_size_gb: 10
```

requirements.txt

```
Flask==1.1.2
Flask-SQLAlchemy==2.4.1
Jinja2==3.0.1
mysql-connector-python==8.0.23
mysqlclient==2.0.3
SQLAlchemy==1.3.23
gunicorn==20.1.0
```

Comment: In the logs do you see any error message regarding that the connection attempt to the DB failed? Can you share it?

Comment: Your connection string is not correct for App Engine Flexible. Review this example code: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/blob/HEAD/cloud-sql/mysql/sqlalchemy/main.py